# JQuery load() fires before image is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to change src attribute of my image and then read the width of the new image. Unfortunately JQuery load() function seems to fire before the image is loaded and width is set. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

```js
function buildLoad(rc){
 alert(rc.width());
}

var rc = $('img.myimg');
rc.attr({'src':'https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/379x674q90/661/Nt07gm.jpg?'+Math.random()});
rc.load(buildLoad(rc));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="myimg" src="">
```

Comment: Apparently it is a known issue documented by JQuery here: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: You can use setTimeOut() and call your method after a delay of 200 milliseconds or so. Based on the filesize and internet speed this number may need to be higher or lower that is why it is not the best way to go.

Comment: Thank you, Nawed! Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try the onload event

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var rc = $('img.myimg');
    rc.load(function(e){

        console.log("Height:" + e.currentTarget.height, "Width:" + e.currentTarget.width)

    });
    
    rc.attr({'src':'https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/379x674q90/661/Nt07gm.jpg?'+Math.random()});
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="myimg" src="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically in your code the problem was that you called the `buildLoad(rc)` regardless of the `load` event. What you needed to do is call a wrapper function that will run once the `load` was done:

```
rc.load(function() { buildLoad(rc) })
```

```js
function buildLoad(rc){
 alert(rc.width());
}

var rc = $('img.myimg');
rc.attr({'src':'https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/379x674q90/661/Nt07gm.jpg?'+Math.random()});
rc.load(function() { buildLoad(rc) })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="myimg" src="">
```

> Regardless - there are several known issues regarding the `load` event on images among current browsers which you can read more about [here](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

Comment: Thank you, Dekel. It's funny because when I run the snippet here it works properly but when I implement your improvement into my website then it still returns "0" for image width.

Comment: Can you show the exact implementation of the code in your website?

Comment: It turned out that I put display: none on the parent element before the image was loaded and that is why I get such effect. Thank you, Dekel!

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery one function.

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Try the following code.

$("img.myimg").one("load", function() {
        // Get width of the image
    }).attr("src", "New path");